# Web project transfered between users loads different Global Assembly Cache Libraries

Tags: asp.net

Web project transfered between users on same machine loads different Global Assembly Cache Libraries when Compiled/debug

I have taken over a project from another developer.

It is an ASP.NET VB Web Project developed in Visual Studio 2010

I am working on the same machine that the previous developer used.

I have access to the previous developers account.

If I login as the previous developer and Go to File -> Open Web Site… I can get the web site to debug and run.

If I copy the website to my user name and try to open the website I notice different results in the output window:

```
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):  
Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\
v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'      

'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): 
Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\
v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'
```

The difference is v4.0_1 versus v4.0_2

There are others.

The end result is that the browser window opens to a blank page and continually produce error messages in output window.

How do I stop this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried to reset the iis? Execute iisreset

Comment: You should try to cleanup ~\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment folder. Besides, look that there's a iis server running, and bugging it!